# How to apply advanced styling for all portlets of one kind

Tags: css, liferay, portlet

I want to apply my advanced styling for asset-publisher portlet for all the instances which is created and will be created in feature. (I want to update the width of the preview of the document not the width of the portlet)
This is my code:

```
.yui3-dd-draggable.yui3-resize{
width: 75% !important;
}
```

I tried like this

```
.portlet-borderless.portlet-asset-publisher.yui3-dd-draggable.yui3-resize{
width: 75% !important;
}
```

or

```
.portlet-borderless.portlet-asset-publisher. yui3-dd-draggable.yui3-resize{
width: 75% !important;
}
```

or

```
.portlet-borderless.portlet-asset-publisher
.yui3-dd-draggable.yui3-resize{
width: 75% !important;
}
}
```

or

```
.yui3-dd-draggable.yui3-resize{
.portlet-borderless.portlet-asset-publisher
width: 75% !important;
}
}
```

or all this variants but with .portlet-borderless.portlet-document-library instead of .portlet-borderless.portlet-asset-publisher
but nothing succeed.

So do u have any suggestions how to make my css default for all asset-publisher portlets in my site ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, all Asset Publisher instances use this class in the wrapping div element, as specified in the platform `liferay-portlet.xml`:

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>101</portlet-name>
    ...
    <css-class-wrapper>portlet-asset-publisher</css-class-wrapper>
    ...
</portlet>
```

**Styling of every Asset Publisher instance**

CSS selector `.portlet-asset-publisher` is enough.

```
.portlet-asset-publisher {
    width: 75% !important;
}
```

**Styling of the asset detail only**

By default, Liferay wraps the asset content to a div with `asset-full-content` class.

```
.portlet-asset-publisher.asset-full-content {
    width: 75% !important;
}
```

**If you need more control**

Both the list and the detail can be customized with ADT templates or JSP hooks. If you need complete control over the HTML output, I suggest to implement custom ADT template for the list (see [Rich Summary](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Rich+Summary+for+Asset+Publisher)) and custom display style for the detail (ie. JSP hook - in LR 6.2, the detail still cannot be customized with ADT; see [example](http://liferay-blogging.blogspot.cz/2011/04/tutorial-how-to-enhance-liferay-asset.html)).

Comment: I dont want to change the width of whole portlet. I want to change the width only of the enlarged document view when u press the magnifier. So I have to tell somehow what exactly I want to change!

Comment: That wasn't clear from the question at all. I suggest you edit the question to specify the goal exactly. See my updated answer.